# Calling a specific item in an indexed For loop

Tags: vba, outlook

I’m trying to understand the difference between iterating an object in a For Each loop vs calling a specific item in an indexed For loop.

I wrote the first macro which works as expected except it exits prematurely. I think because I’m making changes to the list I’m iterating on. To fix this I worked from the bottom of the list up but calling item(i) does not return an object.

Code that exited part way through the list.

```vb
Sub MoveItems()

    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim traiged_emails_A As Outlook.Folder
    Dim traiged_emails_B As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim olMail As Variant

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = myInbox.Items
    Set triaged_emails_A = myInbox.Folders("triaged_emails_A")
    Set triaged_emails_B = myInbox.Folders("triaged_emails_B")
    Set myItems = myInbox.Folders("triaged_emails").Items

    For Each olMail In myItems
        If InStr(olMail.HTMLBody, "Some Tag") <> 0 Then
            olMail.Move triaged_emails_A
        Else
            olMail.Move triaged_emails_B
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Code that attempts to fix the above failure but I can’t call the specific item as an object.

```vb
Sub MoveItems()

    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim traiged_emails_A As Outlook.Folder
    Dim traiged_emails_B As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim olMail As Variant

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = myInbox.Items
    Set triaged_emails_A = myInbox.Folders("triaged_emails_A")
    Set triaged_emails_B = myInbox.Folders("triaged_emails_B")
    Set myItems = myInbox.Folders("triaged_emails").Items

    For i = myItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set olMail = Inbox.Items(i)
        If InStr(olMail.HTMLBody, "Some Tag") <> 0 Then
            olMail.Move triaged_emails_A
        Else
            olMail.Move triaged_emails_B
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

The above hits the line `Set olMail = myInbox.item(i)` and returns

> Object Required.

Comment: There are some strange ways, respectively: `Set myItems = myInbox.Folders("triaged_emails").Items`, which is correct if a `InBox` subfolder named  "triaged_emails" exists. You previously used `Set myItems = myInbox.Items` which is useless since you set it again. Then, You iterate between mails in "triaged_emails" subfolder, but try using `Inbox.Items(i)`. Firstly, `InBox` is not declared, not set, it is nothing as the error said. Secondly, even if you would use `myInbox.item(i)`, it may work, but it couldn't return what I suppose you need, extracting a (random) item from the parent folder...

Comment: Replace `Set olMail = Inbox.Items(i)` with `Set olMail = myInbox.item(i)`, and always start your code with `Option Explicit`.

Comment: @FaneDuru Sorry, I was tired. Your comment must be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line

```
Set olMail = Inbox.Items(i)
```

with

```
Set olMail = myItems(i)
```

or

```
Set olMail = myItems.Item(i)
```